# Efficient data manipulation with pandas based on 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Here's my code with 2 dataframes:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3, 5, 2], [2, 2, 3, 5, 2], [3, 2, 3, 5, 2], [10, 2, 3, 5, 2]]),
                   columns=['ID', 'itemX_2', 'itemK_3', 'itemC_5', 'itemH_2'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3, 10,10,10], [2,3,5, 2,3,5, 2,3,5, 2,3,5], [20,40,60, 80,100,200, 220,240,260, 500,505,520]]).T,
                   columns=['ID', 'Item_id', 'value_to_assign'])
```

Based on df2 I want to modify df1

Expected output:

```py
df_expected_output = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 20, 40, 60, 20], [2, 80, 100, 200, 80], [3, 220, 240, 260, 220], [10, 500, 505, 520, 500]]),
                   columns=['ID', 'itemX_2', 'itemK_3', 'itemC_5', 'itemH_2'])
```

I have done it with iterating over columns and some operations. Hovever in my example i got more columns and rows in dataframes, so its pretty slow. Someone know how to do it in fast efficient way? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution. `pivot` df2 to have a format similar to df1 and then replace column by column by matching on the number after the last '_'.

```
df2_pivot = df2.pivot(index='ID', columns='Item_id', values='value_to_assign').rename_axis(None, axis=1)

df3 = df1.set_index('ID')
for c in df3:
    df3[c] = df2_pivot[int(c.rsplit('_', 1)[-1])]
```

Or, using a dictionary comprehension for the second part:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({c: df2_pivot[int(c.rsplit('_', 1)[-1])]
                    for c in df1.columns[1:]},
                    index=df1['ID']).reset_index()
```

output:

```
>>> df3.reset_index()
   ID  itemX_2  itemK_3  itemC_5  itemH_2
0   1       20       40       60       20
1   2       80      100      200       80
2   3      220      240      260      220
3  10      500      505      520      500
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be:

1. Stack the original df which is to be replaced.
2. grab the index and split the second index to get values after `_`
3. using `pd.Index.map`, map the values of these index from df2
4. Create a dataframe keeping this mapped value as value and the stacked multiindex as index and then unstack them.

---

```
s = df1.set_index("ID").stack()
i = s.index.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1].split("_")[1]))
v = i.map(df2.set_index(["ID",df2['Item_id'].map(str)])['value_to_assign'])
out = pd.DataFrame({"value":v},index=s.index)['value'].unstack().reset_index()
```

---

```
print(out)

   ID  itemX_2  itemK_3  itemC_5  itemH_2
0   1       20       40       60       20
1   2       80      100      200       80
2   3      220      240      260      220
3  10      500      505      520      500
```

Answer (score 2):

### [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

We can use `pivot` to reshape the dataframe `df2` so that we can easily use `replace` method to substitute the values in `df1`

```
df1.set_index('ID').T.replace(df2.pivot('Item_id', 'ID', 'value_to_assign')).T
```

---

```
    itemX_2  itemK_3  itemC_5  itemH_2
ID                                    
1        20       40       60       20
2        80      100      200       80
3       220      240      260      220
10      500      505      520      500
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the columns of df1 and perform a `pd.merge` :

```
for col in df1.columns:
    if col == 'ID': continue
    df_temp = pd.merge(df1.loc[:, ['ID', col]], df2, on = 'ID')
    df1[col] = df_temp[df_temp[col] == df_temp['Item_id']]['value_to_assign'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

output:

```
   ID  itemX_2  itemK_3  itemC_5  itemH_2
0   1       20       40       60       20
1   2       80      100      200       80
2   3      220      240      260      220
3  10      500      505      520      500
```